# Creating custom HTML extension to render scripts at the end of the document from the partial views

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want my scripts to load at the end of the document from my partial views. In short, I want to implement the extension for HtmlHelper. To achieve this I'm trying the following solution, here are my extension methods:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static HtmlHelper Script(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<object, HelperResult> template)
    {
       htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["_script_" + Guid.NewGuid()] = template;
       return HtmlHelper.Empty;
    }

    public static HtmlString RenderScripts(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
       foreach (object key in htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items.Keys)
       {
          if (key.ToString().StartsWith("_script_"))
          {
             var template = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[key] as Func<object, HelperResult>;
             if (template != null)
             {
                 htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(template(null));
             }
          }
       }
       return HtmlHelper.Empty;
    }
}
```

In my _Layout.cshtml I have written the following:

```
<body>
<!--some code-->
@Html.RenderScripts()
</body>
```

And in my partial views:

```
@Html.Script(@<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/sampleJs.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>)
```

There is one thing in this solution which I don't understand: the layout file is always executed first, so the @Html.RenderScripts() is executed first and @Html.Script(...) after that, so scripts won't be loaded at all. If I call @Html.RenderScripts() in the partial view it works but it has no point to do like that because scripts are loaded in the middle of the document.

So any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure if this is a good answer but I look into adding `@RenderSection` in your layout rather than an HTML extension. something like `<body>
<!--some code-->
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>` then in your partials put your JS in `@section scripts{ js here }`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorpage.rendersection?view=aspnetcore-2.1 That should achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: So I should remove my custom extension entirely and just add @section scripts {...} in my partials?

Comment: Obviously test it before removing entirely, but if it does what your are looking for, and I think it will. I would recommend using the built in function

Comment: I have written just like that, but unfortunately it doesn't work. It is not possible to load scripts from partial views at the end of the document by default. That's why I needed the extension class. Anyway thanks.

Comment: I think I figured out why it doesn't work. When I call the partial view I use AJAX to load the view in some container, just like that: 
success: function (result) {
                    $('#dynamic-content').empty();
                    $('#dynamic-content').html(result);
}

and the _Layout is already loaded, so @Html.RenderResources() method is not called anymore.